# Unable to run as debug JBOSS project from IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jboss

I am able to run a JBOSS project without debugging.
However, when I try to run the project in debug mode I get the following message in the event log:

```
5:02:17 PM All files are up-to-date
5:02:21 PM All files are up-to-date
5:02:21 PM Error running ProjectConfiguration
           Invalid arguments : Already listening
           [timeout, port, localAddress]
```

I have killed all the java.exe processes on my machine. Any ideas?

### Update

I setup a fresh project completely. I am now getting the following:

```
6:06:56 PM Error running JBOSS Local: Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:9157): java.net.SocketException "socket closed"
6:06:56 PM Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
           Unable to ping server at localhost:8080
```

AND this:

```
ERROR: transport error 202: failed to attach to shared memory connection: The system cannot find the file specified
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_shmem failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
Disconnected from server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try remote debugging by starting JBoss with this uncommented in bin/standalone.conf.bat:

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=y,suspend=n
```

Then in IntelliJ, start a remote debug session against localhost:8888.